# How to generate binary patterns with different sparsity levels?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to generate a set of binary patterns with different specified sparsity levels. The issues I am having with my are

1. the numbers of patterns for each sparsity level are the same, I want it to be random.
2. I don't have much control over the number of generated pattern since I am using the `int()` function.

```py
import numpy as np
def rand_bin_array(p,N):
    arr = np.zeros(N)
    K=int(p*N)
    arr[:K] = 1
    #np.random.seed()
    np.random.shuffle(arr)
    return arr
perc1 = 0.1
perc2 = 0.6
perc = np.linspace(perc1,perc2,80) #perc1 and perc2 are the start and end of my sparsity range 
x = []
bits = 250
for i in perc:
    for j in range(int(1100/len(perc))):  #j is a counter for the loop. 1100 are the original number of patterns I want.
        x.append(rand_bin_array(i,bits))
```

Expected results:
1100 patterns with different sparsity levels

Actual results:
1040 patterns with different sparsity levels, I know the reason for this issue but I can't think of a way to fix it.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Editted.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out - I added some constants:

```
import numpy as np

def rand_bin_array(p,N):
    arr = np.zeros(N)
    K = int(p/100.0*N)            # create that many % ones
    arr[:K] = 1
    np.random.shuffle(arr)
    return arr

perc1 = 20                          # between 20%
perc2 = 70                          # and 70%
perc = np.linspace(perc1, perc2, 5) # create 5 values  
print(perc)

bits = 50                           # create arrays of 50 values
how_many = 2                        # two for each %
x = []
for percent_ones in perc:
    for _ in range(how_many):
        # create 10 different bit-arrays with percent ones
        x.append(rand_bin_array(percent_ones,bits))

print(x)
```

To get an output of:

```
[20.  32.5   45.  57.5  70. ]  # 5 percentages between 20 and 70%

# around 20%ish
[array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), 
 array([0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.,
       0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]), 
 # around 30%ish
 array([0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.,
       1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.]), 
 array([0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.]), 
 # around 45%ish
 array([0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.,
       0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.]), 
 array([0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.,
        0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0.,
        0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.]), 
 # around 57%ish
 array([1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.,
        1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.]), 
 array([0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1.,
        0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.,
        1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.]), 
 # around 70%ish
 array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.,  0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.]), 
 array([1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.])]
```

---

You can use a `np.geomspace()` of the same size as `perc` and modify the amount generated per percentage rate:

```
import numpy as np

def rand_bin_array(p,N):
    arr = np.zeros(N)
    K = int(p/100.0*N)            # create that many % ones
    arr[:K] = 1
    np.random.shuffle(arr)
    return arr

perc1 = 20                          # between 20%
perc2 = 70                          # and 70%
perc = np.linspace(perc1, perc2, 5) # create 5 values 

bits = 50                           # create arrays of 50 values 
total = 100                         # total arrays

# initial amounts for total//2
how_many = np.geomspace(1,total//2,len(perc),True,int)
# add up on parts to reach total
how_many = [x + (total-sum(how_many)//len(how_many)) for x in how_many]
how_many[-1] += total-sum(how_many)

x = []
for count,percent_ones in zip(how_many,perc):
    for j in range(count):
        # create 10 different bit-arrays with percent ones
        x.append(rand_bin_array(percent_ones,bits))

print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks! The number of patterns per sparsity are still the same e.g. `2` for 45%ish and `2` for 57%ish and so on. Also, when using this method the total number of patterns have to be divisible by the length of `perc` or by `how_many`. For example I can't generate `1100` patterns for `80` `perc`s

Comment: @motaha how do you want to modify the number of patters per sparsity?

Comment: I want it to be random. One way I just thought of is to generate a larger number of patterns e.g. `2000` and then pick `1100` at random. Is there another way?

Comment: @motaha  You have to be a bit creative. I added a possible way to do increasing samples per percent batch

Comment: @motaha if you want a set of 80 frequencies you can do 80x14=1120, currently you do 80x13, then delete 20 at random. Alternatively 55x20, 50x11, 100x11 or 110x10 would all give you 1100 samples. What's special about 80 and 1100? 1200 samples would give a huge range of integer factors.

Comment: @PatrickArtner The np.geomspace isn't working it is giving me arrays with all ones. Also, in line 7 `how_may = ...` is that a typo should it be `how_many`?

Comment: @TlsChris Thanks. The 80 and 1100 are arbitrary numbers I just need something that is generic.

Comment: motaha Perhaps you could specify number_of_frequencies, number_of_samples of each then calculate the total number of arrays generated, number_of_frequencies * number_of_samples.  Which is what @PatrickArtner's solution is in effect doing.

Comment: @mo If you use the code I provided you get arrays that are **not** all ones - I made it simplier for you by editing the "complete" code for the 2nd version. This should be enough to get you started.